# SQL Server: Max date query returning nothing but null

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, null

I've researched this, but haven't found anything that has worked.  I'm looking to return the max date for multiple columns, some of which have null values. My query is returning nothing but null for every column. How can I get the actual max dates? Thanks in advance.

```
create table Results
(
    PatientName varchar(50),
    Bordetella datetime,
    [Canine Distemper] datetime,
    Rabies datetime
);

select 
    PatientName, Bordetella, [Canine Distemper], Rabies
from 
    (select 
         PatientName, 
         ReminderName,
         DueDate
     from 
         Results) d
pivot
(
  max(DueDate)
  for ReminderName in (Bordetella, [Canine Distemper], Rabies)
)piv
;
```

Comment: Have you got some sample data too? Also can you check your Create Table syntax. I don't think it matches up with your query

Comment: Also you have `rabies` in your main `SELECT` but not in your subquery.

Comment: @JNevill That's fine

Comment: @Tom, if it's absent from the subquery then it's not in context for the main query. However, I assume it's just the bad example, and not the reason for OP's main issue.

Comment: @JNevill The subquery wouldn't be looking at 'Rabies' as it is a value in the column, not a column heading.

Comment: No. It's a field. It is in the CREATE DDL as a datetime. It's in the `SELECT` list of fields, but absent from the derived table generated by the subquery. It's present again in the PIVOT as a field and is still out of context. I suspect it's just bad transposing from OP's actual query to an example for SO.

Comment: As said in an earlier comment. I didn't think the query matched up with the create table syntax. As they're missing all of their input columns in the subquery from the `create table` syntax I've assumed that that is wrong and not what @user7963586 has in their table. If it is then I'll admit I'm wrong, but if that's the case then they've got more issues then just missing 'Rabies'

Comment: Have you tried `COALESCE`? (Never tried it with an IN statement but it may work here)

Comment: What is datatype for DueDate column?

Comment: @Kannan Kandasamy, it's datetime.

Comment: @Tom, What changes would you propose?  I don't really know what I'm doing.

Comment: If it is datetime it should return correct data. You might require to show the sample errored input dataset and expected output

Comment: @user7963586 I'd start by updating your example to accurately represent what you're doing at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

This should be reading:

```
create table Results
(
    PatientName varchar(50)
    ,ReminderName varchar(50)
    ,DueDate datetime
);

select 
    PatientName
    ,Bordetella
    ,[Canine Distemper]
    ,Rabies
from (
    select 
         PatientName 
         ,ReminderName
         ,DueDate
    from Results
) d pivot (
    max(DueDate) for ReminderName in (Bordetella, [Canine Distemper], Rabies)
) pvt
```